# cannot connect to api server with retrofit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

im trying to make an android app with retrofit library, but it seems like i can't connect into the server. But, i dont really get any specifi reason why is this happening. I already put access_network_state and internet permission on manifest. Also the api works normally when i open it with browser.

[image: Error Logcat]

Here is my code for retrofit interface

```
@GET("seasons/now")
suspend fun getCurrentSeason(@Query("page") page: Int = 1): Response<GenericResponse<DataItem>>
```

And here is my code for instance creation

```
@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideOkHttp(logger: HttpLoggingInterceptor) = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(logger)
    .connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build()

@Provides
@Singleton
fun provideJikanApi(okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): JikanApi = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .client(okHttpClient)
    .build().create(JikanApi::class.java)
```

Comment: "Here is my code for retrofit interface" -- that does not match your screenshot. Your Retrofit interface refers to a `seasons/now` path. Your screenshot does not.

Comment: oh yeah wrong screenshot sir, but the error is also the same. that screenshoot was when i tried with another endpoint

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  add in manifest inside application

Comment: doesn't work at all sir

Comment: Please share browser url

Comment: it already worked, i clean and rebuild the project and also uninstall the app on my phone. dont really know what is wrong here

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the manifest inside your application

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Comment: doesn;'t work sir

Answer (score 0):

Define domain `api.jikan.moe` in `network_security_config.xml`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain>api.jikan.moe</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: also didn't work sir

Comment: The error message suggests that the device is offline - or app has no permission to access the internet.

Comment: it has, i think its bugged. Since after restarting my phone its working properly